# Yasnippet invoked org-time-stamp function inserts double timestamp

Tags: org-mode, yasnippet, time-date

I created a `yasnippet` template to quickly timestamp a note I'd like to make in `org-mode`. The body of the `yasnippet` file reads

```
$0 
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: `(org-insert-time-stamp nil t t)`
:END:
```

However, the effect is the `CREATED` property being populated with double inactive timestamps, e.g., `:CREATED:  [2015-06-16 Tue 10:08][2015-06-16 Tue 10:08]`. Why is this behavior occurring, and how do I prevent the redundant timestamp?

References:

- [Elisp - Avoid prompt in interactive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938018/elisp-avoid-prompt-in-interactive-function)
- [in org-mode, how to insert timestamp with today's date?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7250/in-org-mode-how-to-insert-timestamp-with-todays-date)

*Note*: Trying either one of the methods described in the reference links yields the same doubled timestamp result.

Comment: You may wish to investigate using `org-capture`, which provides for an option to insert at point:  *To insert the capture at point in an Org buffer, call `org-capture` with a `C-0` prefix argument.*  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Using-capture.html  You can create your own templates -- inserting the current date is a simple as adding `CREATED: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a>>` for an active stamp . . .  For templates, see:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Capture-templates.html#Capture-templates  Be sure to read the doc-string for `org-capture-templates`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because `org-insert-time-stamp` inserts a time stamp (like the name says), but also *returns* the time stamp.  Yasnippit inserts the return value but you're also left with the one inserted by the function call.  A fix is to capture the return value, leaving only the inserted value: `(let ((x (org-insert-time-stamp nil t t ))))`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for that explanation, @erikstokes.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from an answer found in [Elisp - Avoid prompt in interactive function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24344714/2623701), the following body of the `yasnippet` file *works*, but I'm sure there's a better solution using `(org-insert-time-stamp)` or similar. This also doesn't address the peculiar double timestamp behavior described in the original question.

```
$0
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: `(insert (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M]"))`
:END:
```

*NOTE*: This solution does oddly leave two spaces between `:CREATED:` and the inserted timestamp. I'm not sure why.

Comment: it works if you use `\`(format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M]" nil nil)\`` without the surrounding `(insert ... )`. This prevents double posting and also avoids the "modified buffer" error which I still get with the solution of @ersikstokes. For details check: https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#org9804f4c

Comment: You are inserting something into a buffer: why would you *NOT* expect the buffer to be modified?